# UnsatisfiedLinkError in spark EMR job with native library

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, java-native-interface, native, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a spark job that uses native shared library (.so). I'm using --jars to copy my .so to all executors (and file seems to be there, along the spark .jar app), but somehow I'm failing to set up environment find and use the .so. Tried --conf spark.executor.extraLibraryPath and -Djava.library.path, but not really sure what paths to use..
Is there an easy way to make it work? (using AWS EMR 4.5.0, spark 1.6.x)

my spark-submit :

```
spark-submit \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-java-options \
--jars s3://at/emr-test/asb_UT/libSplineFitWrapperJava.so \
--class com.SplineFittingDummy \
s3://at/emr-test/asb_UT/asb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
s3://at/emr-test/asb_UT/testPoints01.xml \
s3://at/emr-test/asb_UT/output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with way .so was build. After trying out different settings and available setups (solaris & sfw, debian & g++ 4.6, ...) that failed I tried to compile .so on EMR and everything is working now.
Though it would be helpful if Amazon could provide some docker image with their setup, so we can compile without actually copying all source code to EMR..